# Module XXX found, but does not contain package XXX

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, proto3

Not so familiar with Golang, it's probably a stupid mistake I made... But still, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

So, I got a proto3 file (let's call it `file.proto`), whose header is as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package [package_name];
option go_package = "github.com/[user]/[repository]";
```

And I use `protoc`:

```
protoc --go_out=$GOPATH/src --go-grpc_out=$GOPATH/src file.proto
```

So far so good, I end up with two generated files (`file.pb.go` and `file_grpc.pb.go`) inside `/go/src/github.com/[user]/[repository]/`, and they are defined inside the package `[package_name]`.

Then, the code I'm trying to build has the following import:

```
import (
    "github.com/[user]/[repository]/[package_name]"
)
```

And I naively thought it would work. However, it produces the following error when running `go mod tidy`:

```
go: downloading github.com/[user]/[repository] v0.0.0-20211105185458-d7aab96b7629
go: finding module for package github.com/[user]/[repository]/[package_name]
example/xxx imports
    github.com/[user]/[repository]/[package_name]: module github.com/[user]/[repository]@latest found (v0.0.0-20211105185458-d7aab96b7629), but does not contain package github.com/[user]/[repository]/[package_name]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Go version is `go1.19 linux/amd64` within Docker (`golang:1.19-alpine`).

Note: I also tried to only import `github.com/[user]/[repository]`, same issue obviously.

**UPDATE**:

OK so what I do is that I get the proto file from the git repository that **only** contains the proto file:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repository]/file.proto
```

Then I generate go files from that file with `protoc`:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. file.proto
```

Right now, in current directory, it looks like:

```
 - directory
 | - process.go
 | - file.proto
 | - github.com
   | - [user]
     | - [repository]
       | - file.pb.go
       | - file_grpc.pb.go
```

In that same directory, I run:

```
go mod init xxx
go mod tidy
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build process.go
```

The import directive in `process.go` is as follows:

```
import (
    "xxx/github.com/[user]/[repository]"
)
```

Now it looks like it finds it<s>, but still getting a gRPC error, which is weird because nothing changed. I still have to figure out if it comes from the issue above or not</s>. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us the `module` line from the `go.mod` file in your `github.com/[user]/[repository]/[package_name]` (or, more likely, `github.com/[user]/[repository]`) and confirm the location of that file within the repo ([info](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-dir)).

Comment: @Brits Hmmm - well, that’s the thing. There is no `go.mod`, only the `.proto` file as I want it to be agnostic (it is used by python and go clients). How do you think I should proceed?

Comment: So you have not committed the generated `.go` files? To pull from github the files need to be in github... Simplest alternative is to just copy them into a folder in the go module you are working in. (other options are [replace](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) or [workspaces](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces))

Comment: `So you have not committed the generated .go files?` That's correct. I think I already tried the easy alternative you mentioned. If both generated *.pb.go files are in the same folder as the code I'm trying to build, what would the "import" directive be? I tried several variations with no luck.

Comment: Don't put them in the same folder, create a subfolder. The import depends upon the `module` line in your `go.mod` (see [this](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path)). Basically if `module github.com/foo/bar` and you put proto in subfolder `proto` then `import github.com/foo/bar/proto`.

Comment: Note for clarity: you can actually put them in the same folder as other stuff; just make sure the `package` line at the top is the same..no need to import if you do that as they are in the same package. I do recommend using a subfolder (easier to manage if generated code is seperate).

Comment: I updated the question (see after the `UPDATE` tag) to describe what I did. I went for the easy alternative, and it looks like it kinda works. Could you tell me if it seems right that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really a number of questions in one; I'll try to provide some info that will help. The initial issue you had was [because](https://go.dev/ref/mod#resolve-pkg-mod)

> At least one file with the .go extension must be present in a directory for it to be considered a package.

This makes sense because importing `github.com/[user]/[repository]` would be fairly pointless if that repository does not contain any `.go` files (i.e. the go compiler could not really do anything with the files).

Your options are:

1. Copy the output from `protoc` directly into your project folder and change the `package` declarations to match your package. If you do this there is no need for any imports.
2. Copy (or set `go_out` argument to `protoc`) the output from `protoc` into a subfolder of your project. The import path will then be the value of the `module` declaration in your `go.mod` plus the path from the folder that the `go.mod` is in (this is what you have done).
3. Store the files in a repo (on github or somewhere else). This does not need to be the same repo as your `.proto` files if you "want it to be agnostic" (note that 2 & 3 can be combined if the generated files will only be used within one code base or the repo is accessible to all users).

Option 1 is simple but its often beneficial to keep the generated code separate (makes it clear what you should not edit and improves editor autocomplete etc).

Option 2 is OK (especially if `protoc` writes the files directly and you set `go_package` appropriately). However issues may arise when the generated files will be used in multiple modules (e.g. as part of your customers code) and your repo is private. They will need to change `go_package` before running `protoc` (or search/replace the `package` declarations) and importing other `.proto` files may not work well.

Option 3 is probably the best approach in most situations because this works with the go tooling. You can create `github.com/[user]/goproto` (or similar) and put all of your generated code in there. To use this your customers just need to `import github.com/[user]/goproto` (no need to run `protoc` etc).

**Go Modules/package intro**

The [go spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Import_declarations) does not detail the format of import paths, leaving it up to the implementation:

> The interpretation of the ImportPath is implementation-dependent but it is typically a substring of the full file name of the compiled package and may be relative to a repository of installed packages.

As you are using [go modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod) (pretty much the default now) the implementations rules for resolving package paths (synonym of import path) can be [summarised as](https://go.dev/ref/mod#resolve-pkg-mod):

> Each package within a module is a collection of source files in the same directory that are compiled together. A package path is the module path joined with the subdirectory containing the package (relative to the module root). For example, the module "golang.org/x/net" contains a package in the directory "html". That package’s path is "golang.org/x/net/html".

So if your "module path" (generally the top line in a `go.mod`) is set to `xxx` (`go mod init xxx`) then you would import the package in subfolder `github.com/[user]/[repository]` with `import xxx/github.com/[user]/[repository]` (as you have found). If you got rid of the intervening folders and put the files into the `[repository]` subfolder (directly off your main folder) then it would be `import xxx/[repository]`

You will note in the examples above that the `module` names I used are paths to repo (as opposed to the `xxx` you used in `go mod init xxx`). This is intentional because it allows the go tooling to find the package when you import it from a different module. For example if you had used `go mod init github.com/[user]/[repository]` and `option go_package = "github.com/[user]/[repository]/myproto";"` then the generated files should go into the `myproto` folder in your project and you import them with `import github.com/[user]/[repository]/myproto`.

While you do not **have** to follow this approach I'd highly recommend it (it will save you from a lot of pain!). It can take a while to understand the go way of doing this, but once you do, it works well and makes it very clear where a package is hosted.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer, I appreciate!